# Xcode 4 Ad-Hoc Distribution - Unable to Download

Tags: xcode4, distribution, wireless, adhoc

I had recently upgrade our development machine to Xcode4 and after the initial interface change has gone quite smoothly.
I'm now in the process of using Ad-Hoc distribution on it for the first time so I followed this guide to set up profiles/schemes etc.  http://diaryofacodemonkey.ruprect.com/2011/03/18/ad-hoc-app-distribution-with-xcode-4/

This is the process I took:

1/ Setup a new provisioning profile under distribution.  I selected Ad-Hoc, the correct App and my UUIDs.

2/ Installed the profile within Xcode 4.

3/ In xcode duplicated the Release Configuration and named it Ad-Hoc.

4/ Under Code-Signing made sure Ad-Hoc had the new profile selected.

5/ Edit Archive scheme and selected 'Ad-Hoc' Build Configuration.

6/ Select Product > Archive and made sure the profile listed was correct.

7/ On save screen selected 'enterprise distribution' and entered the App URL and Title.

8/ Copied the resulting ipa archive, plist and mobileprovision (downloaded in point 1) to our http server.

9/ Added the required html to and pointed mobile Safari to it.

10/ Selected the mobileprovision which installed without a problem.

11/ Selected the App which begins to install resulting in "Unable to Download" at about 90%.

I've tried several potential solutions from other posts but they all result in the same thing.  This is used to work fine in Xcode 3 (using normal developer account, NOT enterprise) and as far I can tell I'm not really doing anything different so what am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: Open the Scheme you are using to edit it. Then check if in ALL the build phases (Build, Run, Test, Profile, ...) the Build Configuration is set correctly. If not set it to the correct configuration and build it again.

If this does not work ad a new Entitlements.plist to your project and add a new value with the key `get-task-allow` to NO.

Edit: Have you tried to make `Product > Build For > Build For Archiving` and then `Product > Archive`.
This worked for me.

Comment: Tried it earlier with no change.  Entitlements.plist is added and is listed under Code Signing within the Project details.  get-task-allow is set to NO.

Comment: See my edit. And again: Did you set the Build Configuration in ALL steps (Build, Run, Test, Profile, ...) in the scheme?

Comment: Thanks again.  Tried it but has same problem.  I assumed Product > Archive would perform a build anyway?
I've been through the all the phases in the Scheme Project > iOS Device and they are set correctly.

Do you know whether I'm correct in thinking that the mobileprovision now gets included within the ipa file and doesn't have to be installed seperately on the device?

Comment: Yes this is correct. I did it without providing the profile on the website and it worked. Don't know what's wrong in your case. Did you set the url to the ipa file?

Comment: dasdom, did you resolve this yet? I'm having the exact same issue. I am doing the same thing with the same settings, followed Lee M's suggestions...same result at about 90%. Was working fine in Xcode 3.

Comment: I've been trying various things for the past 3 days but still have exactly the same problem.  I'm at a loss with what to do next.

Answer (score 0):

we just had the same problem (and we still have it for one device only working on iOS5 Beta, not sure if it is related. All other devices work.), some tips that could help :

Apple dev site:

- your provisioning profile could need to be renewed on the apple web site.
- on the apple web site check that the device is linked to the provisional profile in the "Device" section. In the "provisional profile" section, the "Edit" feature could lie to you. To add a missing device to a provisional profile, go the "provisional profile" section then uncheck and check back the missing device (the lying part from apple web site ;))

in xcode:

- I switched deployment target OS from 4.0 to 4.2
- I plugged my iPhone and selected it as target before to create the archive.
- this issue doesn't depend on the "team provisioning file", we could build a working archive with another provisioning file too.

If it can help too, I created a doc for distributing the Moodle app but it's generic to any app I guess: http://docs.moodle.org/dev/how_to_distribute_iPhone_test_app